# Is there an efficient way to optimize my serialized code?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

**This question have a lack of details. So, i decided to create another question instead edit this one. The new question is here: [Can i parallelize my code or it is not worth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17937438/can-i-parallelize-my-code-or-it-is-not-worth)**

I have a program running in CUDA, where one piece of the code is running within a loop (serialized, as you can see below). This piece of code is a search within an array that contain addresses and/or NULL pointers. All the threads execute this code below.

```
while (i < n) {
    if (array[i] != NULL) {
        return array[i];
    }
    i++;
}
return NULL;
```

Where `n` is the size of `array` and array is in shared memory. I'm only interested in the first address that is different from NULL (first match).

The whole code (i've posted only a piece, the whole code is big) is running fast, but the "heart" of the code (i.e, the part that is more repeated) is serialized, as you can see. I want to know if i can parallelize this part (the search) with some optimized algorithm.

Like i said, the program is already in CUDA (and the array in device), so it will not have memory transfers from host to device and vice versa.

My problem is: `n` is not big. Difficultly it will be greater than 8.

I've tried to parallelize it, but my "new" code took more time than the code above.

I was studying reduction and min operations, but i've checked that it's useful when `n` is big.

So, any tips? Can i parallelize it efficiently, i.e., with a low overhead?

Comment: I dont understand what you are asking here. How can "Array have more than one address"? Whyis there a difficulty if "it will be greater than 8"? It isn't clear what you want to do, why what you have done isn't acceptable and what that approach is.

Comment: When you say that `array` may have more than one address, do you mean that `array` elements can assume values corresponding to more than one address value? But, regardless to that, you are perhaps answering to your question by yourself: GPU is convenient when large arrays are concerned. Roughly speaking, CPUs are faster than GPUs and, when the arrays are small, you pay too much in the overhead of setting up a kernel launch. So, although you do not provide your approach, with some common sense I would say that I would not be surprised that porting your code wouldn't be worth.

Comment: @talonmies, i apologise for my wrong question. I said it was CPU code because the code run in a serialized way, like CPU code. Sorry. I've changed the phrase about the array and addresses. Check if you understand now, the way i've asked was really confused. It's edited now.

Comment: @JackOLantern, i apologise for the way that i've asked my question. I edited it. Now i explain it better. I know, maybe i have answered my question. But this is what i want to know, if there is an optimized algorithm for a small `n`. Sorry for the way that i've writed my question, it was really confused.

Comment: I have a clever one-line answer to this question (hint: `__ffs(__ballot(array[threadIdx.x] != NULL)`), but I don't want to waste your time if it isn't what you are looking for. So @Blufter, if you want to improve and clarify your question, then you should specify exactly HOW you use this code. In the CUDA context, it's crucial to know how it is called: Is it called by every thread, only one thread, or some threads? What does it return if all values are NULL (you don't show that, so your code is incomplete).

Comment: @harrism, it's called by every thread. And if all values are NULL the return is NULL. I'll edit it now. To use your idea i'll need to change how threads are launched in my program (i use 2-d block, and the way how __ballot works will not fit now), i'll see how to reorganize the threads and try it. It seems to be a good idea. Thanks

Comment: Is the `array` variable shared (in which case you can do some kind of intra-block or even intra-warp search) or does every thread have its own `array`?

Comment: @ChristianRau, array is located in shared memory.

Comment: @Blufter In this case it shouldn't be difficult to let the threads search in parallel. If `n` could be guaranteed to be <=32, you can even do it without any synchronization. Or, even if not doing it in parallel, you can at least let only a single thread from the block do the search, which frees all but a single warp of this block from all this work. But you should definitely add this information (that the `array` is shared) to the question, which results in completely different solutions (and would resolve the many confusions all the others have about this question).

Comment: @harrism, unfortunately i can't use your idea. The threads which need to do the search is in y-dimension, thus it's not in the same warp. I thought to change x-dimension threads with y-dimension threads. But i can't do this because the code would lose memory coalescing. And lose the memory coalescing will bring an great overhead that is not worth it.

Comment: @ChristianRau, i can see now that my question haven't all information needed yet. Look to my last comment, where i cited that i have x and y dimension threads. I'm sorry about this confusion.

Comment: @Blufter Huh? So not all threads need to do this search? Yet this doesn't change anything for the validity of the simpler single-thread approach. And don't forget to add that stuff about x and why into your question, too (probably with some more clrarification *what (th) you're actually doing*).

Comment: In the end it doesn't really matter which threads perform the search anyway, so you can still do it in parallel. All you want to do is search some element in an array and this for all threads (and if some thread don't need the result, then be it so, they can just ignore it). If this is not the case and your code example isn't what is actually done, then by any means write a proper question in the first place.

Comment: To make it a bit more rigourous: If a) every thread must do this computation (i.e. `i` is different for each thread and therefore no computation is duplicated), and b) you have plenty of threads to fill the GPU, then the conclusion is simple: there is no need to parallelize this loop.  Only if either statement a) or b) is false should you worry about parallelizing it. If only y-dimension threads need to do search, I assume you mean 1 thread per row. This falsifies a), implying it can be parallelized. Since `array` is in `__shared__` memory, your concern about coalescing is moot.

Comment: @harrism, i wrote another question with all the details that i can give. I explain about my memory coalescing and i'll be grateful if you can read and answer it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17937438/can-i-parallelize-my-code-or-it-is-not-worth

Comment: @ChristianRau, i listened to your advice and wrote another question with all the details. I'll be grateful if you can read and answer it. Thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17937438/can-i-parallelize-my-code-or-it-is-not-worth

Comment: @Blufter You could have just updated this question instead of opening another one if it is just a more detailed description of this same problem.

Comment: Please don't create duplicate questions. We try to keep the unanswered ratio low on the cuda tag. By leaving this unanswered and creating another one you are only raising the number of unanswered questions.

Comment: @ChristianRau, sorry. I saw your comment about "write a proper question" and interpreted as a new question. I won't do it anymora. Thank you.

Comment: @harrism, sorry. I didn't know about it. I just think that it was better create a new question than edit all the question. But i won't do it anymore. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping things simple, one of the major limiting factors of GPGPU code is memory management. In most computers copying memory to the device (GPU) is a slow process.

As illustrated by http://www.ncsa.illinois.edu/~kindr/papers/ppac09_paper.pdf:

***"The key requirement for obtaining effective
acceleration from GPU subroutine libraries is minimization of
I/O between the host and the GPU."***

This is because I/O operations between host and device are SLOW!

Tying this back to your problem, it doesn't really make sense to run on the GPU since the amount of data you mention is so small. You would spend more time running the memcpy routines than it would take to run on the CPU in the first place - especially since you mention you are only interested in the first match.

One common misconception that many people have is that '*if I run it on the GPU, it has more cores so will run faster*' and this just isn't the case.

When deciding if it is worth porting to CUDA or OpenCL you must think about if the process is inherently parallel or not - are you processing very large amounts of data etc.?

Comment: I've edited my question, i said that is was CPU code because it runs serialized, just like CPU. But it is already in GPU, thus i'll not have memory transfers between host and device. But i want to know yet if there is a way to parallelize the "first match search" efficiently for a `n` small (n < 8). I appreciate your help.

Comment: My point is - for small n there is no point in trying to implement a parallel implementation for it. That's not what the GPU is designed for. If you're only searching for the first match, then the whole thing is inherently a serial process. Even if you could do this in parallel it would surely just over complicate things. n is so small it doesn't seem worth it. That's just my understanding of the situation.

Comment: tjenks, i wrote another question with much more details. I'll appreciate if you read it and answer what your think, if it is woth or not. Thank you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17937438/can-i-parallelize-my-code-or-it-is-not-worth

Answer (score 1):

Since you say the `array` is a shared memory resource, the result of this search is the same for each thread of a block. This means a first and simple optimization would be to only let a single thread do the search. This will free all but the first warp of the block from doing any work (they still need to wait for the result, yet don't have to waste any computing resources):

```
__shared__ void *result = NULL;
if(tid == 0)
{
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<n; ++i)
    {
        if (array[i] != NULL)
        {
            result = array[i];
            break;
        }
    }
}
__syncthreads();
return result;
```

---

A step further would then be to let the threads perform the search in parallel as a classic intra-block reduction. If you can *guarantee* `n` to *always* be <= 64, you can do this in a single warp and don't need any synchronization during the search (except for the complete synchronization at the end, of course).

```
for(unsigned int i=n/2; i>32; i>>=1)
{
    if(tid < i && !array[tid])
        array[tid] = array[tid+i];
    __syncthreads();
}

if(tid < 32)
{
    if(n > 32 && !array[tid]) array[tid] = array[tid+32];
    if(n > 16 && !array[tid]) array[tid] = array[tid+16];
    if(n > 8 && !array[tid]) array[tid] = array[tid+8];
    if(n > 4 && !array[tid]) array[tid] = array[tid+4];
    if(n > 2 && !array[tid]) array[tid] = array[tid+2];
    if(n > 1 && !array[tid]) array[tid] = array[tid+1];
}

__syncthreads();    
return array[0];
```

Of course the example assumes `n` to be a power of two (and the `array` to be padded with `NULL`s accordingly), but feel free to tune it to your needs and optimize this further.

Comment: This code is brittle and is likely to fail if the hardware or compiler optimizations change significantly (they have in the past, they will in the future).  Plus, for the single warp case you can do it with a single line of code: `__ffs(__ballot(array[threadIdx.x] != NULL))` (sm_20 or later).

Comment: @harrism Then feel free to downvote it. By the way, if the hardware changes significantly, you have to rework it anyway, GPU code is still far from write once run anywhere, at least if concerned about performance. But feel free to write your own answer using intrinsic stuff I've never heard about.