# Can i parallelize my code or it is not worth?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

I have a program that must process a lot of data and classify it in groups based in some pattern. I'll talk about it a little.

This data is represented like a matrix, where each column is an different element which is divided into "sub-elements". The program take this "sub-elements" and go walking through each pattern (the pattern is represented by a DFA - Deterministic Finite Automaton *) to see to which group the element belongs (the element doesn't belong to more than one group).

- *I use the matrix in this way to have memory coalescing when port it to GPU.*

The image below explain the data organization in a visual way.

[image: http://img203.imageshack.us/img203/6163/g9w9.jpg]

- *Obviously the data-set is much bigger than 4 elements*

**CPU-CODE** - First i had this program writen in CPU code. It works totally serialized. The program take each sub-element from an element and check if the element belongs to one
group checking the first pattern. If don't, look the second pattern. And so on. When the first element is classified, the second element is checked, then the third and so on.
**/CPU-CODE**

How you can see, this code can be much faster if parallelized. Then the program was coded in CUDA.

**GPU-CODE** - To run the code in GPU with low memory transfers, all the data and the automaton was transferred to GPU memory before the "classify code" starts. The difference now is 
that i can launch a lot of threads and blocks and each thread will take one element and classify it. The image below explain how it is done in GPU.

[image: http://img441.imageshack.us/img441/4732/53ra.jpg]

The GPU code is much faster than the CPU code. **/GPU-CODE**

**Now the question**:
Like i said the pattern is checked walking into an automaton. The automaton have some states and each state have some transitions. The number of transitions is hardly larger than 6. Due to memory limitations, automaton is not represented in default mode that requires just one look in the table to get the next state (table encoding).

My encoding requires more than one look to get next state. To get the next state i take the sub-element and check if the first transition is triggered by it. If don't, i check the second transition and so on.

If it's not clear enough, both CPU and GPU codes above walks in a serial way within the automaton states. In other words, it checks the first transition to see if we have a match to next state. If don't, check the next transition and so on.

I want to parallelize this search within each state. In other words, i want one thread per transition. Like i said, the number of transitions within a state hardly is larger than 6. I know that it seems to be unnecessary to parallelize it because the small number of transitions, but this part of the code (match) is repeated several times.

I tried to parallelize this search within each state, but the execution time was bigger than the serial code. **I'll explain how i've done my naïve implementation below:**

To this test i used an automaton that have at most 4 transitions per state (but it can have less than 4). So i launched 4 threads in Y-dimension of the thread-block (the X-dimension threads take the elements and the Y-dimension threads take the sub-elements) and create one array in shared memory that will store if i have a "transition match" or not. This array have the size of the block (blockDim.x * blockDim.Y) because it is done to all the elements.

The problem is: sometimes i have less than 4 transitions per state, what means that thread 3 for example can check other state that not the one i'm interested and have a wrong match. This problem forces me to make a "first match" search, and i do this search in a serial way, which is the same thing i do before, but now i have an overhead associated to create threads and an array (i set the array elements of array to 0, more overhead). Thus, i did nothing.

Just for make things clear, this image shows what i tried to do.

[image: http://img855.imageshack.us/img855/7576/b0ui.jpg]

I've asked how to do a first-match search in stackoverflow before, but my question was missing some important details about my code and my problem, which i explain here.

So my question is, can i parallelize this search within each state efficiently (even with a small number of transitions) or it is not worth and i should use my serialized GPU code?

If you think i can parallelize, should i use my last code with a better implementation of the "first-match" search or should i use a completely different approach?

Comment: From a brief read through your question I think that you are in a much better position to answer your own question than anyone else.  You might get answers which argue one way or another, hedged about by ifs and buts and assumptions, but program performance analysis is an empirical science, not an argument from first principles, so any such answer will be incomplete and ultimately unconvincing.  You MIGHT (capitals indicating a doubtful tone of voice) get someone who implements (or has implemented) enough of the program to get you some useful data, but don't count on that.  Get prototyping.

Comment: How many elements are there?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, i understand your point and believe that you are right. But i'm kinda new in CUDA, so i put this question here to get some tips like "try it" or "look for this algorithm" and than try each one. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @harrism, i can have a lot of elements. But i take it in a loop. Each iteration take 8192 elements. This number is because the best configuration in serial-cuda implementation i've found is 128 threads and 64 blocks (by empirical tests).

Comment: So you have more than enough computation to fill the GPU.  In that case, it is likely not worth parallelizing this extra dimension, unless it is eliminating redundant computation (which it doesn't appear it is).

Comment: @harrism, thanks for your comment. So in your opinion, to improve my code i shall focus my efforts in other enhancements, like the memory chosen and coalescing memory? Any other tips?

Comment: I would recommend trying the guided performance analysis features in the new Visual Profiler or NSight EE in CUDA 5.5 (officially released today!).